# при нажатии на спиннер вылетает приложение хотя массив записывается

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class Activity_setting extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
public  String sResh;
public  String sText;
public String[] data_resh = new String[999];
public String[] data_text = new String[999];

Button btnAdd, btnUpd, btnDel, btnRead, btnClear;
EditText etResh, etText, etID;
DBHelper dbHelper;
Spinner spinner_resh,spinner_text;
TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
    btnDel.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
    btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

    etResh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResh);
    etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);

    // создаем объект для создания и управления версиями БД
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("mytable", new String[]{"id", "resh", "text"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String s = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

        sResh = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resh"));
        data_resh[i]=sResh;
        sText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));
        data_text[i]=sText;

        TextView infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        s = (s+ data_text[i]+"    "+data_resh[i]+i+"\n" );
        infoTextView.setText(s);
        i=i+1;
    }
    cursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_resh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data_resh);
    adapter_resh.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_resh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.resh_list);
    spinner_resh.setAdapter(adapter_resh);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_text = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data_text);
    adapter_text.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_text = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.text_list);
    spinner_text.setAdapter(adapter_text);

    // заголовок в этой теме нет
    spinner_resh.setPrompt("Title");
    spinner_text.setPrompt("Title_2");

    // выделяем элемент который будет стоять первый
    spinner_resh.setSelection(0);
    spinner_text.setSelection(0);

}
```

лог ошибки

```
process: ru.life.sendremedylite, PID: 4108
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:636)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:631)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.compatMeasureContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:558)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:749)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:774)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:432)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19774)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: плюс заметил что в первый спиннер идет значение 2ой переменной, хотя не понимаю почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что NPE вы ловите потому, что в ваших массивах часть элементов равны `null`, так как в `cursor` было меньше, чем 999 элементов. Думаю, что для решения проблемы вам нужно создавать массив, размер которого совпадает с числом элементов в БД. Для этого сначала можно использовать `ArrayList`, а затем уже создавать массив нужного размера. Попробуйте сделать что-то вроде:

```
ArrayList<String> reshList = new ArrayList<String>();
...
```

Далее вместо `data_resh[i]=sResh;` писать `reshList.add(sResh);`

После обработки всего курсора:

```
data_resh = new String[reshList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < reshList.size(); i++) {
    data_resh[i] = reshList.get(i);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("mytable", new String[]{"resh", "text"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    //cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i = 0;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String sResh = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resh"));
        String sText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));
        data_resh.add(sResh);
        data_text.add(sText);
    }

    cursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_resh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data_resh);
    adapter_resh.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_resh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.resh_list);
    spinner_resh.setAdapter(adapter_resh);
```

долго мучался но чтение помогло, позже увидел ваш ответ,стал использовать arrayList, сначало заметил что если поставить длинну массива 9 и 9 строк в базе забито то все работает, потом прочитал что строковый массив не меняет длинну, потом прочитал про альтернативы , сейчас думаю не сделал ли я ошибку создав одну таблицу для связанных элементов, но не полностью, первый spiner относится ко второму как один ко многим, тоесть в первом массиве элементов меньше,и если заносить в одну таблицу будут повторения, а они мне не нужны, вот и ломаю голову что же делать